# Sendgrid WebHook Not Working & Test sometime fail

Tags: sendgrid, webhooks

i'am using sendgrid WebHook, i already enable Event Notification Here
https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/mail_settings

When i Click Test Your Configuration, its work for 3-4 times, then the next re-test doesnt sent POST to my endpoint.

And Send email doesn't trigger any delivered/bounce/drop/click POST Event , even it's already 'ON' & Checked

[image]

nginx access.log/error.log not showing anything related to sendgrid

here inside my endpoint code, it's return 200 HTTP code.

```
function sendgrid_event(){
  $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
  $events = json_decode($data,true);
  $mydata = print_r($_POST,true);
  file_put_contents('uploads/default/sendgrids/sendgrid-'.date('Y-m-d h-i-s').'.txt', $events.$mydata.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```

any Help?

Comment: the event  start to flow, It's seems delayed, lets see tomorrow

Comment: i was not able to see all email states in sendgrid events input, then i realized i was only parsing first json object from the array webhook sends. some times webhook contains many events in one input like a json array with two events ("processed","delivered"). after seeing it i just updated the code to save all events from the webhook input

Answer (score 1):

After calling Send on the API the message gets queued in/by SendGrid. I assume they use a FIFO queue. After SendGrid's "senders" pull your message out of the queue, process and send it, then the processed event should "eventually" be triggered. Again, this might not be 100% instantaneous. To keep their code humming along I assume their code is written asynchronously and the event may also be queued up and wait for another process to come along to pick it out of the queue and process (call your webhook endpoint). Again all of this might take some time. It also may take a long time when there are issues/outages with their processes.

Comment: today its working good.
i see the server status seems fine yesterday http://status.sendgrid.com/
but thanks for your explanation anyway.